# existence of $a \neq e$ in group such that $a^2=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$G$ - group, $|G|=2k$, $k\in \Bbb N$

Does there exist $a\in G; a \neq e: a^2 =e$?

I think I should somehow use the fact, that there is odd number of elements of $G$ which are not $e$.

Comment: Yes, using that fact is a good idea. Group the elements pairwise in a convenient way, except for those that don't have a partner.

Answer (score 1):

if $a^2 \ne e$, then $a \ne a^{-1}$.

there are $2k-1$ elements of $G$ which are not $e$, so these exist **odd** number of elements of $G$ which satisfy $a^2=e$ but $a\ne e$

Comment: but why does these elements exist?